# pgfmathparse in foreach, use result as node coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgfmathparse

I'm trying to use a counter inside a TikZ picture, and use values resulting on calculations with this counter. Let's say for instance, I want `i` to be ranging from 0 to 9, `j` to be `i*5` and `k` to be `i*10`. I've managed to get this working this way:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,9}
{
\def \j {\pgfmathparse{\i * 5}\pgfmathresult}
\def \k {\pgfmathparse{\i * 10}\pgfmathresult}
\node at (0, -\i) {\tiny \i,\j,\k};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works as I intend to, the output being:

```
0,0.0,0.0

1,5.0,10.0

2,10.0,20.0

3,15.0,30.0

4,20.0,40.0

5,25.0,50.0

6,30.0,60.0

7,35.0,70.0

8,40.0,80.0

9,45.0,90.0
```

Now, and this is where it gets tricky, I want to use the secondary counter, let's say `j` as a coordinate of the nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,9}
{
\def \j {\pgfmathparse{\i * 5}\pgfmathresult}
\def \k {\pgfmathparse{\i * 10}\pgfmathresult}
\node at (0, \j) {\tiny \i,\j,\k};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I end up with this error:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 9.
<inserted text> 
\fi 
<*> mwe.tex
```

Why doesn't it work? What would be the proper way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{\i*5}` etc (untested)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your attempt does not work because the `\pgfmathparse{…}\pgfmathresult`
is not expanded until `\j` is used within the coordinate to the `\node`.
Ti*k*Z, of course, does not expect this, so it fails to parse the
coordinate. To fix this, you can expand the macros at definition time.

Here is, I believe, the most direct analogue of your code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {0,...,9} {
    \pgfmathparse{\i * 5}\edef\j{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{\i * 10}\edef\k{\pgfmathresult}
    \node at (0, \j) {\tiny \i,\j,\k};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is a common pattern, so `\pgfmathsetmacro` provides a shortcut:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {0,...,9} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{\i * 5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{\i * 10}
    \node at (0, \j) {\tiny \i,\j,\k};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Both yield the same result.

Comment: All the answers were great but your one does have the explanation I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Not entirely sure why you get that, but use `evaluate` instead.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach [evaluate=\i as \j using \i*5,evaluate=\i as \k using \i*10] \i in {0,...,9}
{
\node at (0, \j) {\tiny \i,\j,\k};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could also have used `\node at (0,\i*5) ...`.

Answer (score 5):

A solution using `\pgfmathparse` implicitly.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1mm]
\foreach \i in {0,...,9}
  \draw let \n1 = {5*\i}, \n2 = {10*\i} in
  (0, -\n1) node {\tiny \i,\n1,\n2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]