# Strange behaviour of \path coordinate in \foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

For me (using pdflatex: pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)) the following code compiles fine, but if I uncomment the second loop it fails to compile with a "Giving up on this path..." error message. Am I doing something stupid?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path coordinate (P) at (7,10);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \position [count=\posi] in {(0,0), (3,0), (4,1), (5,2), (4,4), (2,5), (1,3)} 
            \path \position coordinate (P\posi);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    % \begin{tikzpicture}
    %     \foreach \position [count=\posi] in {(0,0), (3,0), (4,1), (5,2), (4,4), (2,5), (1,3)}
    %         \path coordinate (P\posi) at \position;
    % \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after `at` you have to use `(` as noted in the manual

> ```
> \path ... coordinate[<options>](<name>)at(<coordinate>) ...;
> ```

This is why `\path coordinate (P\posi) at \position;` is not working, but `\path \position coordinate (P\posi);` is ok.

**EDIT:** As mentioned @marmot in his comment, the problem is that `\position` is not expanded when tikz is parsing for `(` after the `at`.

If you really want to use `at`, I don't know why somebody would, you ca say `... at ([shift=\position]0,0) ...` that force the expansion of `\position`, but in this case if your `\position` was a named coordinate, it will stop to be.

Comment: I guess you'd need to add that there is an expansion issue. Otherwise it is rather confusing because the coordinates start with `(`. The issue is that they are not expanded at the time Ti*k*Z tries to parse the path.

Answer (score 2):

No you do not do anything stupid. Similar expansion issues have been reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357658/121799). Anyway, you have already found yourself a nice way out. Alternatively you could go along the lines in one of the answers to that question.

**OLD ANSWER**: Thanks to @Zarko: Simplest solution: update your TeX distribution.

If you do not want to do that (or cannot do that), you need to put the coordinates into braces since they contain a comma, which is also the separator in the `\foreach` list. If you do not put the braces, older versions of `pgffor` will interpret the first entry as `(0`, and this obviously leads to an error. The same issue will arise in newer versions in which you have more complicated items in the list. Generally, I do not think that the braces hurt.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \foreach \position [count=\posi] in {{(0,0)}, {(3,0)}, 
            {(4,1)}, {(5,2)}, {(4,4)}, {(2,5)}, {(1,3)}} 
            {
                \path \position coordinate (P\posi);
                % \coordinate (P\posi) at \position;
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @TikzerWoods I am talking about `\path coordinate (P) at (7,10);` at the very beginning of the code.

Comment: @TikzerWoods Yes, but this is what the OP is doing in his first loop. Have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357658/121799).